# How to reduce the loading time of a jsp page?

Tags: jsp

There is a page in my application with different tabs. I want to decrease the loading time of the page. So I ended up with this decision to let the page just loads the first tab whenever the page is loading for first time and every other tabs just be loaded when the user clicks on that tab. 
But I don't know what is the best way to do it. Does anybody have any idea how to do it (or a better solution without a lot of change in my code)?

Comment: Hard to say without internal structure - maybe cannot be downloaded in advance? maybe can be ajaxified?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply lazy-loading, with the following approach:

- modify everything which is not needed to be loaded immediately to have an acceptable initial state
- write some code which will fill the gaps upon request
- when the page is loaded, send asynx requests which will trigger the code which fills the gaps server-side
- use the response to actually fill the gaps
- load initially only what is needed and use the strategy described above for everything else